# Prompt user when Back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

Which is the good place to ask user, whether (s)he wants to exit the app when (s)he clicked the back button? I considered the `onPause` and `onStop`, but these methods fires whenever app is gone behind the other apps.

Update:
The app should also ask if user is trying to exit the app from a button (in app itself), not the Back hard key.

Comment: your next question will be how to completely exit the app

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri: No buddy. I already know that. And I also know exiting an app is not a good idea. What I want to do is to prompt user, not exit the app myself.

Comment: That will be great +1 for that I dont know why most user want to close the ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Ask for user's permission to close the
>   app.**

You can do it in the following way;

```
/**
 * Exit the app if user select yes.
 */
private void doExit() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AppDemoActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
    alertDialog.setTitle("AppTitle");
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

> **Which is the good place to ask user,
>   whether (s)he wants to exit the app
>   when (s)he clicked the back button?**

Since, you want to prompt user when (s)he clicked the back hard button, as suggested by others, you can override the [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method and call the above method from there;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    doExit();
}
```

As suggested by [@Martyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290599/prompt-user-when-back-button-is-pressed/6293317#comment7347547_6290629), you can use the [`onKeyDown`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) to achieve the same;

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        doExit();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

> **The app should also ask if user is
>   trying to exit the app from a button
>   (in app itself), not the Back hard
>   key.**

For this, call the `doExit()` from your button's onClick;

```
Button exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
exitButton.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doExit();
    }
});
```

**Related Info:**

- [Implementing effective navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/)

Comment: Maybe instead of 'finish()' one can call 'AppDemoActivity.super.onBackPressed()'

Answer (score 6):

look at this link..

You should not exit your application.

[Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238)

Comment: I don't want to exit the app, I just want to ask for user's consent.

Answer (score 2):

The best place is in the `onBackPressed`.  the only thing you need to keep in mind is that the app behaves 'normally' - that is when the user pressed back they should go to the previous screen - if they press back on the main screen, then it's good to ask if they meant to quit the app.

Comment: What if user selected No on the prompt. How could I cancel the app exit?

Comment: You could override onKeyDown instead then you have more control  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

Answer (score 2):

If it's only when the user presses back (not home or whatever), use [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29).

The doc says:

> Called when the activity has detected
>   the user's press of the back key. The
>   default implementation simply finishes
>   the current activity, but you can
>   override this to do whatever you want.

So if you catch the backpress and don't do anything, the activity is not quit.
If you want to quit, use `finish()`

Comment: What if user selected No on the prompt. How could I cancel the app exit?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question but it ranks high on Google so I figured it could need an **Update**:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit the app?");

    // if user presses "Exit", then he is allowed to exit from application
    builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", (dialog, which) -> finish());

    // if user selects "Stay", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
    builder.setNegativeButton("Stay", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());

    builder.create().show();
}
```