# Beginner Android: Prompt to Leave

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

When the user clicks the back button on the main activity, I would like a dialog to pop up asking the user if he "wants to leave". I am able to create the dialog and implement it but I am unsure of how to make the dialog open when the back button is pressed. Any Suggestions?

Comment: The same question was already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290599/prompt-user-when-back-button-is-pressed

Comment: There are many ways a user can "leave" your main activity -- BACK, HOME, incoming phone call, responding to a `Notification`, etc. BACK is only one of these. Whatever you do to make sure the user does not lose any in-progress work when a phone call comes in is an equally good plan to do if they hit the BACK button.

Answer (score 1):

Which API? This is the easiest way from API 5+

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: +1 correct answer. @drew: Just don't forget to call `finish()` on clicking "Yes" button.